# Как увеличить время выполнения CURL

Tags: curl, centos, timeout, settimeout

Привет. Может кто сможет помочь. Вот такой имею лог.

```
* About to connect() to www.21vek.by port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 178.159.244.234... connected
* Connected to www.21vek.by (178.159.244.234) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=www.21vek.by,OU=Board,O=Triovist OOO,L=Minsk,ST=Minsk,C=BY,serialNumber=190806803,businessCategory=Private Organization,incorporationCountry=BY
*   start date: Nov 11 00:00:00 2016 GMT
*   expire date: Dec 11 23:59:59 2017 GMT
*   common name: www.21vek.by
*   issuer: CN=GeoTrust EV SSL CA - G4,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US
> GET /get/price/marketYandex/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: www.21vek.by
> Accept: */*
> 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.10.1
< Date: Tue, 30 May 2017 17:31:04 GMT
< Content-Type: application/xml
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30
< Set-Cookie: 21vek=elr1sst5de0d3b2m54poo83tj1; expires=Tue, 30-May-2017 21:31:03 GMT; Max-Age=14400; path=/; domain=21vek.by
< P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
< Set-Cookie: Settings[u_connid]=592dac57f0316; expires=Wed, 30-May-2018 17:31:03 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; domain=21vek.by
< Set-Cookie: Settings[u_source]=Q2FrZQ%3D%3D.9ksKOtlH2Gq3M2tSIOmKJHDl9p0%3D; expires=Wed, 30-May-2018 17:31:03 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; domain=21vek.by
< Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="marketYandex.yml";
< 
{ [data not shown]

100 1213k    0 1213k    0     0   270k      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--  280k
100 1213k    0 1213k    0     0   221k      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--  227k
100 1837k    0 1837k    0     0   274k      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--  332k
100 3165k    0 3165k    0     0   455k      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--  661k
100 8444k    0 8444k    0     0  1052k      0 --:--:--  0:00:08 --:--:-- 1739k
100 12.2M    0 12.2M    0     0  1385k      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:-- 2481k
100 16.9M    0 16.9M    0     0  1723k      0 --:--:--  0:00:10 --:--:-- 3530k
100 21.6M    0 21.6M    0     0  1996k      0 --:--:--  0:00:11 --:--:-- 4608k
100 26.5M    0 26.5M    0     0  2244k      0 --:--:--  0:00:12 --:--:-- 4649k
100 31.5M    0 31.5M    0     0  2457k      0 --:--:--  0:00:13 --:--:-- 4659k
100 35.8M    0 35.8M    0     0  2595k      0 --:--:--  0:00:14 --:--:-- 4755k
100 40.6M    0 40.6M    0     0  2749k      0 --:--:--  0:00:15 --:--:-- 4776k
100 45.4M    0 45.4M    0     0  2882k      0 --:--:--  0:00:16 --:--:-- 4831k
100 49.7M    0 49.7M    0     0  3005k      0 --:--:--  0:00:16 --:--:-- 4919k
100 54.1M    0 54.1M    0     0  3085k      0 --:--:--  0:00:17 --:--:-- 4799k
100 59.5M    0 59.5M    0     0  3197k      0 --:--:--  0:00:19 --:--:-- 4920k
100 64.6M    0 64.6M    0     0  3290k      0 --:--:--  0:00:20 --:--:-- 4936k
100 69.3M    0 69.3M    0     0  3363k      0 --:--:--  0:00:21 --:--:-- 4931k
100 73.4M    0 73.4M    0     0  3425k      0 --:--:--  0:00:21 --:--:-- 4850k
100 77.7M    0 77.7M    0     0  3466k      0 --:--:--  0:00:22 --:--:-- 4834k
100 82.3M    0 82.3M    0     0  3492k      0 --:--:--  0:00:24 --:--:-- 4600k
100 86.5M    0 86.5M    0     0  3550k      0 --:--:--  0:00:24 --:--:-- 4629k
100 90.5M    0 90.5M    0     0  3560k      0 --:--:--  0:00:26 --:--:-- 4404k
100 95.7M    0 95.7M    0     0  3612k      0 --:--:--  0:00:27 --:--:-- 4400k
100 99.6M    0 99.6M    0     0  3644k      0 --:--:--  0:00:27 --:--:-- 4459k
100  104M    0  104M    0     0  3696k      0 --:--:--  0:00:29 --:--:-- 4698k
100  110M    0  110M    0     0  3740k      0 --:--:--  0:00:30 --:--:-- 4663k
100  114M    0  114M    0     0  3785k      0 --:--:--  0:00:30 --:--:-- 4978k
100  119M    0  119M    0     0  3813k      0 --:--:--  0:00:31 --:--:-- 4940k
100  124M    0  124M    0     0  3869k      0 --:--:--  0:00:32 --:--:-- 5172k* Connection #0 to host www.21vek.by left intact

* Closing connection #0
```

Из него видно, что `curl` выполняет лишь 30 секунд задачу, а потом отрубается.

Как заставить его выполнять задачу минут 10? Вычитал, что есть параметры `--connect-timeout` и `--max-time`

Но что-то на них не реагирует `curl`.

OS — CentOS

```
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

Comment: Вообще то не совсем понятно что за лог, откуда. Поясните?

Answer (score 2):

Curl ни при чем. У вас на сервере, к которому идет обращение, выполняется процесс php (из лога видно - php 5.6). На этом сервере надо скорректировать [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/ru/info.configuration.php) в php.ini, по умолчанию этот параметр как раз 30 секунд.

Если к настройкам удаленного сервера доступа нет, никакие настройки на вашей машине не помогут. Дробите вашу задачу на куски, выполняющиеся менее 30 секунд и ставьте эти куски в очередь. Стандартный, кстати, подход запуска длинных задач на php.

Answer (score 1):

Помогло добавления в

`/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf`

параметров
`IPCCommTimeout = 30000` и `FcgidMaxRequestLen = 30000`